# Using AJAX to change a file in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to duplicate a file and put some information in. First I used the form-method-action (Method 1). This worked. But I wanted to used Ajax to stay on the same page. So then I created Method 2 but this method doesn't work.

This is how my folder looks like. The 'Document.docx' has '$naam' in it's file

[image]

HTML METHOD 1:

```
<form method="post" action="kopie.php">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" name="factuur" id="factuur" placeholder="factuurnaam"></li>
        <li><input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" placeholder="naam"></li>
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 class="ans"></h2>
</form>
```

HTML METHOD 2:

```
        <ul>
            <li><input type="text" name="factuur" id="factuur" placeholder="factuurnaam"></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" placeholder="naam"></li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"></li>
        </ul>
        <h2 class="ans"></h2>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'kopie.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        factuur: factuur,
                        naam: naam
                    }
                    success: function() {
                        $('#ans').html("It worked");
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
```

PHP FOR BOTH METHODS:

```
    $factuur = $_POST['factuur'];

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    //This is the main document in a .docx file.
    $fileToModify = 'word/document.xml';
    $wordDoc = "Document.docx";
    $newFile = $factuur . ".docx";

    copy("Document.docx", $newFile);

    $naam2 = $_POST['naam'];

    if ($zip->open($newFile) === TRUE) {

        $oldContents = $zip->getFromName($fileToModify);

        $newContents = str_replace('$naam', $naam2, $oldContents);

        $zip->deleteName($fileToModify);

        $zip->addFromString($fileToModify, $newContents);

        $return =$zip->close();
        If ($return==TRUE){
            echo "Success!";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }

    $newFilePath = 'factuur/' . $newFile;

    //Move the file using PHP's rename function.
    $fileMoved = rename($newFile, $newFilePath);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Well my goal is to create a duplicate of Document.docx and change some internal text of it. With the html of Method 1 it makes a new file and changes the text. With Method 2, no file is created

Comment: You might also want to throw in a `even.preventDefault()` in the click event.

Comment: Until you open the developer tools in the browser and see if there are errors, there isn't much we can do to help you. Others have pointed out that you're not sending any data, but you haven't even confirmed if jQuery is installed or you're using a webserver.

Comment: When I remove 'success: function() {..}', it does work. But I don't understand why. In the Developer Tools it says it has an error syntax

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your input value on your data.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'kopie.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        factuur: $('input[name=factuur]').val(),
        naam: $('input[name=naam]').val()
      },
      success: function() {
          $('#ans').html("It worked");
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: That's not all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your AJAX - I'll note the changes.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //keeps the page from refreshing

        $("#submit").click(function() {
        //notice I'm gathering the form data here.
        var data = { 'factuur' : $("#factur").val(),
                     'naam' : $("#naam").val()
         }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'kopie.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: data, //referencing the data variable above
                dataType: html
                success: function() {
                    $('#ans').html("It worked");
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Nothing happens unfortunately

Comment: I may not have gotten all the syntax correct. But you get the idea right? Try checking for console errors.